# Can I refer to a previous question I asked within the content of a new question?

Tags: discussion, ethics

I am thinking about a new question that is based on a premise that I stated in (I did not claim that it - the premise -  was a new idea), and comments and answers  I received in response to a previous question that I posted.

Can I (and, if so, should I- ethically/ or in good taste etc.) identify the question title for reference within the body of the text of the new question?

Comment: I took out your tag request because that should be posted separately. You can bring it up in [chat] if you like, to get preliminary feedback before posting on meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, it's a good idea to refer to previous questions (yours or other people's) when doing so is useful. But don't just use the question *title*; you should include a link to it. If you include just the URL of the question, the SE software will automatically convert the link to display the question title, e.g. if I write

> ```
> https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508
> ```

then I get [Can I refer to a previous question I asked within the content of a new question?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508).

Alternatively, you can give your own link text by using the appropriate Markdown:

> ```
> [the question about referring to previous questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508)
> ```

gives [the question about referring to previous questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508).

Answer (score 3):

Sure, why not?*

* We can't really give you clear advice on yes or no without seeing the exact wording of the question in mind. But in most cases, it's fine. Imagine "If pV = nRT, then what happens in a nozzle flow" can easily lead to "Why does pV = nRT anyway?"

Comment: I see you have read  some of  my answers - I originally did describe why PV=nRT  in the errata question, but I edited it out - the answer seemed too long. I appreciate the touch of levity in your comment,

Comment: @JohnFletcher Actually, I didn't read anything beforehand! My only contribution around here is fluid dynamics related and that was the first thing that popped into my head...

Comment: The odds of that are in the entropy realm! I have answered three questions - one was on the purpose of a combustion chamber and nozzle in a rocket engine, another was on the possible misinterpretation of Boyle's Law in a textbook.

Comment: @JohnFletcher Well, combustion, rockets, fluids, and computer simulations are all my PhD area... So I imagine we'll be crossing paths again and again. Welcome to the community (and sub-community)!